# NULL Reference When Accessing Properties From Class

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public static class AppUser
{
    public static int TestNum
    {
        get { return 999; }
    }

    public static BO.User User
    {
        get
        {
            BO.User _user;

            _user = (BO.User)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["User"];

            if (_user == null)
            {
                _user = new BO.User();
                _user = DLL.Security.GetUserByGuid(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UID"].Value.ToString());
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] = _user;
            }
            return _user;
        }
    }
}
```

In the code-behind of an aspx page, both of these lines work fine:

```
        Response.Write(BLL.BO.AppUser.TestNum.ToString() + "<br>");
        Response.Write(BLL.BO.AppUser.User.ID.ToString());
```

In a class, this line works:

```
        int t = BLL.BO.AppUser.TestNum;
```

But the following line gives me a null reference:

```
        BLL.BO.User u = BLL.BO.AppUser.User;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Run it through the debugger, check to see what's `null`. There are a few possibilities here and they may differ depending on _how_ you're calling this. (A good example might be if you're calling this method without an active `HttpContext`, that is, outside the standard request/response model where `HttpContext.Current` would be `null`) Perhaps the "UID" cookie doesn't exist?

Comment: What is BLL?  You don't say

Comment: BLL is just a folder I have those classes in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this must be the line causing the problem:

```
_user = DLL.Security.GetUserByGuid(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UID"].Value.ToString());
```

And of that line, it doesn't seem like anything could be null except "Request.Cookies["UID"]. If I access your site for the first time, I wouldn't expect "UID" to be set yet so it would make sense that you'd get a NullReferenceException if you're requesting the page for the first time.

Comment: It appears that the System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session is null when accessing from my class but not from the aspx page. This is an internal application so that cookie will be set before the user can even get to these pages.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that since I was calling the method trying to access the AppUser class from a web service, it wasn't initiating the Session. I added [WebMethod (EnableSession = true)] to my web method and it's working now. Thanks to everyone for responding.